# Why can't I inherit from Eigen::Matrix?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, eigen3

I have [this](https://github.com/Kitware/kwiver/blob/957895f35f0d46a6fd572686e10f83415bdb355d/vital/types/point.h#L52) class:

```cpp
template < unsigned N, typename T >
class MY_EXPORT my_point : protected Eigen::Matrix< T, N, 1 >
{
public:
  using vector_type = Eigen::Matrix< T, N, 1 >;

  my_point() : vector_type{ vector_type::Zero() } {}
  using vector_type::vector_type;
};
```

My Linux (GCC) build is fine. However, on Windows (MSVC 15.9.16), I get [really strange errors](https://open.cdash.org/viewBuildError.php?buildid=6180125):

```
c:\include\eigen3\eigen\src\core\densebase.h(482): error C2338: THIS_METHOD_IS_ONLY_FOR_1x1_EXPRESSIONS (compiling source file c:\code\my_point.cxx) [C:\workspace\KwiverWindows\build\vital\vital.vcxproj]
  c:\include\eigen3\eigen\src\core\densebase.h(481): note: while compiling class template member function 'const float &Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>::value(void) const'
          with
          [
              Derived=Eigen::Matrix<float,4,1,0,4,1>
          ] (compiling source file c:\code\my_point.cxx)
  c:\include\eigen3\eigen\src\core\matrixbase.h(50): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>' being compiled
          with
          [
              Derived=Eigen::Matrix<float,4,1,0,4,1>
          ] (compiling source file c:\code\my_point.cxx)
  c:\include\eigen3\eigen\src\core\plainobjectbase.h(100): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>' being compiled
          with
          [
              Derived=Eigen::Matrix<float,4,1,0,4,1>
          ] (compiling source file c:\code\my_point.cxx)
  c:\include\eigen3\eigen\src\core\matrix.h(180): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<float,4,1,0,4,1>>' being compiled (compiling source file c:\code\my_point.cxx)
```

It looks like the compiler is trying to instantiate inappropriate methods (e.g. a later error is trying to instantiate `w()` for a 3-vector). What am I doing wrong? (Why is this not a problem when using `Eigen::Matrix` directly?)

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/2-Nb7E) is a live demo.

Comment: Linux and Windows are operating systems.  What are the compilers and versions you're using?

Comment: Sorry; it's MSVC 15.9.16 (also added to question). I haven't gone digging, but I believe it is working on several versions of GCC (I think at least 4.8 and 9.2).

Comment: Provide a [mre]! What is `using vector_type::vector_type;` supposed to do?

Comment: Okay, interesting data point... the error only happens if the class is exported (`__declspec(dllexport)`). With that tweak, the above *is* the MRE; link to live demo added as proof. Also, it seems you need to [read up on constructor inheritance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#Inheriting_constructors). (Also doesn't seem to be limited to a specific MSVC version.)

Comment: Regarding only happening with dllexport this may shed some light: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190927-00/?p=102932

Comment: @BrianWalker, that... doesn't make sense? I mean, I understand the "because it has to instantiate everything" argument, but why doesn't an explicit instantiation (which I am also doing) also cause the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Eigen doesn't use SFINAE/`enable_if` to hide "inappropriate" members, it just relies on them never being instantiated (with static assertions if someone tries to use them). As a result, an `Eigen` class — at least, `Eigen::Matrix` — cannot be explicitly instantiated.

This can be seen with a trivial example:

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Core>
template class Eigen::Matrix< double, 3, 1 >;
```

([Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GciUnH))

The real mystery is why GCC allows explicit instantiations of classes *derived* from `Eigen::Matrix`. MSVC does not, but it seems that MSVC is probably in the right, here.

The short term solution is to not export `my_point`. This requires, of course, that the definitions of all of `my_point`'s methods are either visible in the header, or are individually exported (rather than trying to export the whole class).

The longer term solution would be to fix Eigen so that its types can be explicitly instantiated: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=1768.

Comment: Without the `__declspec` MSVC also compiles your code: https://godbolt.org/z/LIVjS-. And as said in the bz-entry, I don't really see what you actually gain from instantiating a class template here.

Comment: AND, you can at least workaround the static assertions, by disabling them: https://godbolt.org/z/T_Wb6D

Comment: Okay, that's screwy. I am now less convinced that GCC is wrong. Also, I don't think I want to turn off assertions, because I *don't* want someone using the four-scalars ctor on a `my_point<3, T>`. Ultimately, I think the issue is using static assertions where `enable_if` should have been used.